# python/276/bin/python: Exec format error. Wrong Architecture

Tags: linux, python

Getting below error while trying to run python of version 2.7.6 on linux

python/276/bin/python: Exec format error. Wrong Architecture

I am using below linux version,

Linux version 2.6.9-67.ELsmp (brewbuilder@ls20-bc1-14.build.redhat.com) (gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-8)) #1 SMP Wed Nov 7 13:58:04 EST 2007

Comment: You must be trying to run a 64-bit python in a 32-bit OS (or vice versa,...) RHEL 3.4 has been out of service since 2011 (extended support ended in 2014). Where did you get the installation package?

Comment: Thanks @xenoid Got it. Yes my machine is 32 bit and python is 64 bit. Actually it's old machine, I got it(RHEL3.4) when it was released in 2007.